# Optimization problem: Finding the minimum of two functions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima

I am new to optimization problems and would appreciate some insight into solving a fairly simple one.

Referring to the diagram below, let's assume we have two functions, *f(x)* and *g(x)*. We can assume *f(x)* has some negative linear/polynomial correlation and *g(x)* has some positive linear/polynomial correlation. We likewise have two constraints: *y<sub>f</sub>* which denotes the maximum valid output of *f(x)*; and *y<sub>g</sub>* which denotes the maximum valid output of *g(x)*.

Given *f(x)*, *g(x)*, *y<sub>f</sub>*, and *y<sub>g</sub>*; we are tasked with finding the corresponding *x* input values within the valid range for: minimizing *f(x)*, minimizing *g(x)*, and minimizing both *f(x)* & *g(x)*.

[image]

Minimizing for f(x) and g(x) respectively is fairly straightforward using the inverse functions, x<sub>1</sub> = f<sup>-1</sup>(y<sub>f</sub>) and x<sub>2</sub> = g<sup>-1</sup>(y<sub>g</sub>).

So input *x<sub>1</sub>* will give the min for *g(x)* and the max for *f(x)* within the valid range, and conversely input *x<sub>2</sub>* will give the min for *f(x)* and the max for *g(x)* within the the valid range.

So the next question is, what method can be used to minimize both considering any variations on functions *f* and *g*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for optimization to be well-defined, your target needs to be a partially ordered set, and more typically is a totally ordered set. When asking to minimize both $f$ and $g$, you are considering the map $x \to (f(x), g(x))$ which means your target is $\mathbb{R}^2$. While you can put orderings on this set, a much more natural way to handle this is to define a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and compose your original map with this one.

For example, a natural choice is to minimize $f(x) + g(x)$. Or if you care about $f$ more than $g$, you could choose to minimize $3f(x) + g(x)$.

However you must always make a choice as there is no "natural" ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in regards to optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the information, much appreciated. Can you perhaps link an example? having trouble grasping the concepts

Comment: Say $f(x) = x^2 - 5$ and $g(x) = x^3 - 7x + 2$. There is no real sense where you can minimize both because the minimums need not occur at the same value of $x$, but you can instead minimize $(f +g)(x) = (x^2 - 5) + (x^3 - 7x + 2)$.

Comment: Another natural choice is to minimize $\max(f(x),g(x))$, that is, the worst case.